# How to implement system wide conditions in Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel-5

I am creating a Laravel (v5.4) app in which a user can create several 'organisations' and each organisation can have several 'projects'. But at any given time, the user will be working on one organisation only. The user can select the current working organisation by selecting from the list of organisations displayed in the top-menu along with the user`s name. Now, I want that when a project create page is displayed, rather than providing a dropdown to select the organisation, the system should know the selected organisation and create the project under this organisation only. There are many other things to be created like, surveys, tasks etc. and the system must select the default organisation instead of getting it from a dropdown list.

Till now, I have tried to accomplish it by setting the 'organisation_id' in session and retrieving it from session on all the create forms but I was wondering if there is any better way of achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The session is a very appropriate place to store this information. You could add a layer using a middleware to check that the `organization_id` is stored in session between requests and also as a security against user's somehow accessing organizations they don't belong to by checking that the user's id does belong to it. For example:

```
class CanAccessOrganization
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param  \Closure $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (!session('organization_id')) {
              // default to the user's first organization.
              session(['organization_id', Auth::user()->organizations->first()->id]);
        } else {
            // does this user belong to the organization?
            $organization = Organization::find(session('organization_id'));
            if (!in_array($organization->id, Auth::user()->organizations->pluck('id')->all()) {
                // unauthorized! stop the request
                abort(403);
            }
            // set (or reset) the session
            session(['organization_id', $organization->id]);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is very helpful.